# Which are all the unlockable bonuses?

Tags: uncharted-4

I've finished the story mode and collected all the treasures, journal entries, journal notes and optional conversations.

With that I unlocked everything I could see in the `Extras` > `Bonus` submenu:

- Add-Ons

  - Skins (Nathan Drake: 12 skins, Samuel Drake: 11 skins, Victor Sullivan: 5 skins, Elena Fisher: 7 skins, Nadine Ross: 4 skins, Rafe Adler 5 skins)
  - Weapons (21 weapons)
  - Render Modes (19 render modes)
  - Game Play Modifiers (10 game play modifiers)
- Character Gallery (59 portraits)
- Concept Art Gallery (23 galleries)

With all this bought, I still have 31 "Unlock Points". Is this normal? I couldn't find any use for those remaining Unlock Points. If there are other unlockables I didn't mention here, where are they?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the list [here](http://www.gamespot.com/uncharted-4-a-thiefs-end/cheats/), it looks like you have all of the unlockable bonuses.

However, you are able to use UP for multiplayer unlocks. If you have only done single-player, that would explain why you have what seems to be "extra" points.